# How to change Spinner's dropdown width?

Tags: android, xml, spinner, dropdown

[image]

---

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinners"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/location_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/license_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**spinner_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        style="@style/SpinnerButton">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**style.xml**

```
<style name="SpinnerButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

I want drop down style like [picture B]. I have used `dropDownWidth = match_parent`. But it doesn't work. I think it because of this dropDown's parent is Spinner. Each spinner has weight 1. Is there way to apply wide drop down layout?

Comment: Try Popup menu instead of Spinner , Please check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477208/set-popup-menu-to-full-screen

Comment: @ Sachin Shelar >> thanks for your comment. i think you and @Android Dev recommend the same way. right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Spinner DropDown width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235711/change-spinner-dropdown-width)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code , If it works for you .

```
 DealCategorySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.DealCategorySpinner);

    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
        android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(DealCategorySpinner);

        // Set popupWindow width to 800px
        popupWindow.setWidth(800);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```